# I am facing problem while sending fetch response object from one screen to another screen from switch navigator (react-navigation v3)

Tags: javascript, react-native, fetch, react-navigation

```
    this is login screen action function from which i am navigating to another screen .
```

`

```
  loginAction = () => {
            const newState = !this.state.button_toggle;
            this.setState({ button_toggle: newState });
            const { userName } = this.state;
            const { userPassword } = this.state;
            const { schoolCode } = this.state;
            const { loading } = this.state;
            this.setState({ loading: true });
            fetch('url',
                {
                    method: 'post',
                    header: {
                        'Accept': 'application/json',
                        'Content-type': 'application/json'
                    },
                    body: JSON.stringify({
                        //passing param
                        userName: userName,
                        password: userPassword,
                        schoolCode: schoolCode
                    })
                })
                .then((response) => response.json())
                .then((responseJson) => {
                    alert("response");
                    console.log(responseJson);
                    console.log("=======" + responseJson.studentInfo[0]);
                    console.log("N=" + responseJson.studentInfo[0].studentName);
                    console.log("test-" + responseJson.test[0].A);
                    console.log("test-" + responseJson.test[0].B);
                    console.log("test-" + responseJson.test[0].C);
                    const res = responseJson;
                    if (responseJson.Login == "Success" && responseJson.count == 21) {
                        this.setState({ button_toggle: false });
                    }
                    else if (responseJson.Login == "Success" && responseJson.count == 1) {
                        alert("Login Successful 1");
                        this.props.navigation.navigate('Dashboard', {
                            //myJSON: responseJson.studentInfo[0],
                            myJSON: responseJson,
                            Login: responseJson.Login,
                            studentName: responseJson.studentInfo[0].studentName,
                            studentId: responseJson.studentInfo[0].studentId,
                            studentRollNumber: responseJson.studentInfo[0].studentRollNumber,
                            studentImage: responseJson.studentInfo[0].studentImage,
                            classDescription: responseJson.studentInfo[0].classDescription,
                            studentSection: responseJson.studentInfo[0].studentSection,
                        })
                    } else {
                        alert("Login Failed ");
                    }
                }).catch((error) => {
                    console.log(error);
                    alert(error);
                })
        }
```

`getting the data in next screen like this` 

    const Login = this.props.navigation.getParam("Login");
    const K = this.props.navigation.getParam("K");
    const studentName = this.props.navigation.getParam("studentName");
    const studentId = this.props.navigation.getParam("studentId");
    const studentRollNumber = this.props.navigation.getParam("studentRollNumber");
    const classDescription = this.props.navigation.getParam("classDescription");
    const studentSection = this.props.navigation.getParam("studentSection");
    const classId = this.props.navigation.getParam("classId");
    `

this is my navigation

```
const AppSwitchNavigator = createSwitchNavigator({
  LoginScreen: { screen: LoginForm },
  Dashboard: { screen: AppDrawerNavigator }
});
```

inside a stack navigator its working but in inside switch navigator its not working

Comment: Could you provide more info on how it is not working ? What happens exactly ? Do you have some error messages to show ?

Comment: on login screen in console its printing data but on second screen it is printing like "undefined"

Comment: You mean the `console.log()` in your `loginAction()` function ?. Edit your question with who you call `loginAction()` please

Comment: LoginAction is in page1 (LoginScreen ) where iam fetching the data from server , and passing the json object to next screen that is (DashboardScreen ) where iam printing in console it is showing undefined